# Convert Rows to Columns in SQL Server - pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did some readings on this, seems the best option would be to use the pivot function, but I'm still having trouble putting it to actual use.

I have simplified my code below:

```
SELECT o.order_id,  
       chr.charge_name,
       
       Sum(chr.amount) AS amount,
       
       
FROM   [tms].[orders] o
       INNER JOIN [tms].[extra_charges_details] chr
               ON o.sourcetms = chr.sourcetms
                  AND o.order_id = chr.[order]
       INNER JOIN [tms].[probills] p
               ON o.sourcetms = p.sourcetms
                  AND o.order_id = p.order_id
       INNER JOIN [tms].[customers] c on o.UniqueCustomerID=c.UniqueCompanyID
WHERE  o.[date] >= '2021-01-01'

GROUP  BY 
          o.order_id,
          chr.charge_name,
```

The output looks like this:

| order_id | charge_name | amount |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OCA0099128 | FUEL | 49.52 |  |  |
| OCA0101663 | FSC | 0.113 |  |  |
| OCA0101663 | HRS HWY | 40.85 |  |  |
| OCA0101663 | KM HIGHWAY | 1.134 |  |  |
| OCA0101663 | MISC | 89.3 |  |  |
| OCA0101664 | FSC | 0.113 |  |  |
| OCA0101664 | HR CITY | 40.85 |  |  |
| OCA0101664 | KM CITY | 0.65 |  |  |
| OCA0101665 | FSC | 0.093 |  |  |

and I want to make it like this:

| Row Labels | FSC | FUEL | HR CITY | HRS HWY | KM CITY | KM HIGHWAY | MISC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OCA0099128 |  | 49.52 |  |  |  |  |  |
| OCA0101663 | 0.113 |  |  | 40.85 |  | 1.134 | 89.3 |
| OCA0101664 | 0.113 |  | 40.85 |  | 0.65 |  |  |
| OCA0101665 | 0.093 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Any help/recommendation appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think conditional aggregation is usually simpler:

```
SELECT o.order_id,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'FSC' THEN amount END) as fsc,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'HR CITY' THEN amount END) as hr_city,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'HRS HIGHWAY' THEN amount END) as hrs_highway,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'KM CITY' THEN amount END) as km_city,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'KM HIGHWAY' THEN amount END) as km_highway,
       SUM(CASE WHEN chr.charge_name = 'MISC' THEN amount END) as misc
FROM [tms].[orders] o JOIN
     [tms].[extra_charges_details] chr
     ON o.sourcetms = chr.sourcetms AND
        o.order_id = chr.[order] JOIN
     [tms].[probills] p
     ON o.sourcetms = p.sourcetms AND
        o.order_id = p.order_id JOIN
     [tms].[customers] c 
     ON o.UniqueCustomerID=c.UniqueCompanyID
WHERE o.[date] >= '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your query as the heart of the pivot, but leave out the group by and the sum(). Surround it with the pivot:

```
select *
from
(
            SELECT o.order_id,  
                   chr.charge_name,
                   chr.charge_amount
            FROM   [tms].[orders] o
                   INNER JOIN [tms].[extra_charges_details] chr
                           ON o.sourcetms = chr.sourcetms
                              AND o.order_id = chr.[order]
                   INNER JOIN [tms].[probills] p
                           ON o.sourcetms = p.sourcetms
                              AND o.order_id = p.order_id
                   INNER JOIN [tms].[customers] c on o.UniqueCustomerID=c.UniqueCompanyID
            WHERE  o.[date] >= '2021-01-01'
) b
pivot (sum(b.charge_amount) for chr.charge_name in
                        (
                            [FSC], [HR CITY], [HRS HIGHWAY], 
                            [KM CITY], [KM HIGHWAY], [MISC]
                        )
) p
```

Obviously, the values of charge_code have to be hard-coded; but they do in any way you might try to do this.

Comment: My apologies for the delayed response.  What if I have more than one sum() values, say sum(chr.amt) and sum(chr.qty)?

Comment: This is worth a separate question, but briefly: write another query like the above pivoting on the same field and values, with the other field summed; join the two results as sub-queries in a new query, and select as required.